# PHP Using Exchange 2007 to Display Calendar on Website with Real Time Updates

Tags: php, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use PHP to grab calendar information from Exchange 2007 to display the calendar on a webpage. I've figure out how to do all of this with EWS but I was wondering if there is a way to get updates to the calendar in real time so that they are changed on the website instantly. Can Exchange trigger my script whenever a change is made or do I need to poll Exchange at regular intervals? If the latter, is that going to tie up resources?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to poll exchange server using built-in sync function. Since sync is incremental it doesn't produce all that much overhead. You just poll the server at whatever intervals you require (within reason of course). Please refer to this answer for some more info:

[PHP - Syncing MySQL Contacts with Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317212/php-syncing-mysql-contacts-with-exchange/10346124#10346124)